# Will leaving a dead battery inside the laptop damage other components?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, battery

A couple of weeks ago, my battery died. I left it in the laptop. A week later, my hard disk failed too (confirmed this with Dell Diagnostics). Is this because of my mistake (of not removing the battery)?

Also, I want to continue using my laptop but I'm not willing to spend money on both my battery and hard disk. Is it okay if I simply remove the battery and use the laptop with a new hard disk? Will not using a battery damage my hard disk again?

I'm using (or *was* using) a 2.5 years old Dell Inspiron 5547, i3 processor 4GB ram & 500 GB hard disk version.

Comment: Other than old age, one thing has nothing to do with another. Of course, you can replace the hard drive and keep using the laptop, with or without the battery, no impact whatsoever in any other component, but expect other components to fail for exactly the same reason: Old age.

Comment: Case in point: https://superuser.com/questions/1291678/how-do-i-fix-a-0xc000009c-error-windows-10

Comment: Just a note, when multiple components start to die at about the same time, and there is no common event, then there is the possibility that there is a power regulation issue.

Comment: @MichaelBay. Do you think power interruptions when the battery isn't there can cause the hard disk to fail?

Comment: @FrankThomas, do you mean an internal power regulation issue, or external ones (like power fluctuations, power surge etc.)

Comment: Internal, in that an external power issue would be an event you might notice like a blackout, surge, etc. I had a refurb laptop some time ago, and bought an extended warranty on it, which is good because it stopped POSTing three times and each time needed a new motherboard each time. the issue wasn't that they were installing bad motherboards, but that issues with the case power circuitry were causing fluctuation that eventually killed the hardware.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1288921/can-using-a-multiplug-damage-your-laptop-battery#comment1908175_1288921 A good power supply (AC charger) should prevent power surges from affecting the laptop. If Dell Diags reported the HDD only than you have some chance of getting a few years more from that machine but expect components to fail. And yes, a bad power controller board inside, as commented above, can cause many problems.

Comment: The battery serves as a UPS when running on the AC adapter.  Without the battery, a sudden power loss could lead to corruption on your Hard Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Will leaving a dead battery inside the laptop damage other components?**

In my experience, no.

If the battery leaks corrosive fluid over other parts it would likely cause damage. I suspect this sort of leakage is unlikely. If it happened you would be able to see some damage.

> **Is it okay if I simply remove the battery and use the laptop with a new hard disk?**

That works for me. It is possible that the answer depends on your specific laptop. Trying it shouldn't hurt.

I believe in some cases (but clearly not all) the battery is a necessary intermediary between the external power supply (charger) and the internal supply to the motherboard etc.

Comment: Thank you. Just a tiny query specific to my situation: will power failures (resulting in the laptop switching off suddenly) lead to corrupted files?

Comment: @WorldGov. Often, yes. That's why you should regularly backup any important data to multiple media, test recovery from backups periodically and, at least occasionally, rotate some backups offsite (in a fireproof box, ...) and/or pre-encrypted to cloud. USB sticks are far far cheaper and far far more reliable than hard-disk  data recovery services